# Error while trying to import scipy.stats: No module named dual

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I get an error when I try to import scipy.stats:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-320-b66176eb2d0a> in <module>()
----> 1 import scipy.stats

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/stats/__init__.py in <module>()
    319 """
    320 
--> 321 from stats import *
    322 from distributions import *
    323 from rv import *

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/stats/stats.py in <module>()
    191 # Scipy imports.
    192 from numpy import array, asarray, dot, ma, zeros, sum
--> 193 import scipy.special as special
    194 import scipy.linalg as linalg
    195 import numpy as np

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/special/__init__.py in <module>()
    525 from _cephes import *
    526 
--> 527 from basic import *
    528 import specfun
    529 import orthogonal

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/special/basic.py in <module>()
     10 import types
     11 import specfun
---> 12 import orthogonal
     13 
     14 __all__ = ['agm', 'ai_zeros', 'assoc_laguerre', 'bei_zeros', 'beip_zeros',

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/special/orthogonal.py in <module>()
     85 import numpy as np
     86 from numpy import all, any, exp, inf, pi, sqrt
---> 87 from numpy.dual import eig
     88 
     89 # Local imports.

ImportError: No module named dual
```

What exactly is the dual module in numpy? There doesn't seem to be any official documentation on the numpy site. How can I get this or how can I alternatively get scipy.stats to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is basically an index of aliases for functions that scipy uses.

And try the code below and let me know what happens.

`from numpy.numpy.dual import eig`

If it doesn't work then copy the file given below to any file location you see fit and try importing it from there.

`https://github.com/cheshire/numpy/blob/master/numpy/dual.py`

OR you can simply, not import that particular module since scipy can work just fine without it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I just checked and I have that file in a numpy directory. I have two numpy directories, one which is simply called numpy and another one which is called "numpy-1.9.1-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg". The full path is: "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.1-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg". Is this the correct path? Both files contain files called "dual.py" and "dual.pyc", with the same source code as on the github site. Why does python not see that file?

Comment: Reinstalling numpy and scipy resolved this error for me.